# Running T4 TextTemplating on Build server resulting to shelveset

Tags: tfs, automation, t4

We are using T4ToolBox / TextTemplating.15.0 for generating part of the code based on models. Unfortunately it is slow and unstable on local workstations more and more as the project grow.
I am trying to move this process to TFS server and the target is the following process:

1. after checkin on TFS in specified folder (where the models are) the
   custom tool should run on specified .tt files
2. a shelveset should be created from generated files
3. and finally email sent about result

My biggest problems is the following: how to genereate code, exclude these files from checkin (because additional code review is necessary as it may broke the main build) and create shelveset.
Any help is really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean perform text transformation as part of a build process, you can refer to [Generate files with the TextTransform utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility) and [Code generation in a build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process) for details.

To exclude these files from checkin you can create a [`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) file for TFVC or [`.gitignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/ignore-files?tabs=visual-studio&view=vsts#use-gitignore-to-prevent-tracking-of-files) file for Git.

To create the shelveset, you can use the [Shelvesets Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/shelvesets-command?view=vsts)

Comment: I see, that my question was not specific enough, I will dig deeper, but thank you putting me into right direction.